# Shell script to move folders based on file type to its appropriate folder

Tags: linux, shell

So I've been working on a shell script that will look in the downloads folder and check it and its sub directories for specific file types and then move the directory containing those files to the appropriate folder. (e.g an album in the downloads folder containing .mp3 files will get moved to the music folder, a tv show containing .mp4 files gets moved to the videos folder) but I'm having some problems with it and I've no idea what's going on.

Here's the script:

```
#MOVES MUSIC FROM DOWNLOADS TO MUSIC FOLDER

for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.mp3" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Music/
done





for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.flac" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Music/
done






for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.wav" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Music/
done




#MOVES VIDEOS FROM DOWNLOADS TO VIDEOS FOLDER

for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.mkv" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Videos/
done






for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.mp4" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Videos/
done




for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.avi" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Videos/
done




#MOVES IMAGES FROM DOWNLOADS TO PICTURES

for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.jpg" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Pictures/
done





for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.png" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Pictures/
done





for DIR in /home/kevin/Downloads/*/
do
    [ $(find "$DIR" "*.gif" | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && mv "$DIR" /home/kevin/Pictures/
done
```

The funny thing is that it kind of works but not as expected. So in my downloads folder I had two sub directories. One is an album containing mp3's, and another was a tv show containing .mp4's. When I ran the script it moved both of these folders to /home/kevin/Videos. Weird.

So I thought maybe it was some problem in having all this code in one script so I separated each section into it's own script one for moving music called move_music.sh, another for moving videos called move_video.sh. I moved the album and the tv show back to the downloads folder to test these new scripts but the problem is if I run move_video.sh it moves the tv show and the album to the music folder. If I put the folders back into downloads and run move_music.sh it moves both folders to the music folder!

Anybody know what's going on here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try looking at the output of `find "$DIR" "*.oops"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `-name` option to `find` like:

```
find "$DIR" -name '*.mp3'|wc -l
```

And your script seems to be good.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much! :D